# Can't clone using clonezilla cause partitions are too spread all over the partition table

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, clone

I'm trying to clone a HDD of 1 TB on another HDD of 1 TB of exact same size.When I try to clone using clonezilla Disk_To_Disk clone. It says it can't mount several SDA's.I cloned some HDD's back in the day using everything same but never encountered an error.The only problem I can think of is that my partitions looks like this:[image: my partitions looks like this]

I frequently keep extending and shrinking disk and that's why my partitions looks like these.
Is there any way this is the one that's creating the problems.If so, what are the steps I can take to encounter this problem.Also, is there any certain requirement to format the Target disk cause Last time I cloned, I didn't do anything to target disk.
Thanks

Comment: If they're the same size - are there advanced settings? The [imaging option would let you use dd](https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live/doc/01_Save_disk_image/advanced/09-advanced-param.php) but no idea if it would let you clone that way, and that would just do a exact clone. Its slower than partimage (since it also clones empty sectors) but it would work

Comment: I think this one is for Disk_to_image where as I'm trying disk_to_disk

Comment: hence me asking if there's a similar option for disk_to_disk under advanced options

Comment: yes there is and I tried it but it didn't worked